# keep raw data from different vector with different allocator

Tags: c++, vector, allocator

I have a big vector want to cache, in order to avoid copy, I just want to keep the pointer of the original one.
The issue here is, the original vector may have different allocators. So it's impossible to use a vector* to do that (1).
I'm thinking to use a T* and size_t to cache the original data(2). 
My question is:

For (1), is there a way to do so? using a vector* cache another vector with different allocator.

For (2), is that the best way to achieve this goal (avoid copy, different allocator), does it safe?

Thank you!

Comment: *"the original vector may have different allocators"* - at runtime or at compile time?

Comment: My case should be compile time. Different components have different allocator, but use a same lib/class to cache the vector.

Comment: If it's compile time, i.e. the allocator type is fixed at compile time, then why exactly does solution 1 not work? It should be `std::vector<T, MyAllocator>*`  or maybe `std::shared_ptr<std::vector<T, MyAllocator>>`.

Comment: Yes, for a specific one, it's OK. But I mean, only using one member, to cache pointer of std::vector<T, std::allocator> or std::vector<T, MyAllocator>.

Comment: So where and how exactly in your code do you make the choice between `std::allocator` and `MyAllocator`?

Comment: Let's say this is the piece of the code: void fun(vector<int, std::allocator>& vec1, vector<int, MyAllocator>& vec2> { if (xxx) m_cache = &vec1; else m_cache = &vec2;} } How would you implement m_cache without data copy? question (1) and (2).